# Modifying values inside data-bind in knockout

Tags: css, knockout.js

I was developing a page using knockout. I have bind an array to the html as follows

data:

```
{'options':[{'name':'hi'},{'name':'hello'}])
```

html:

```
 <div data-bind="foreach: options">
       <div data-bind="text: name, css: name"></diV>
    </div>
```

Each option have an image and i am using css sprites. and the class name are like

> div.option-`<name>`

css:

```
div.option-hi{
  background-color:black;
}
div.option-hello{
  background-color:black;
}
```

So this will only work if I can append

> "div.option-"

to the name attribute inside
data-bind. Is there anyway I can achieve this without modifying the array and adding one more attribute in to the populate array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't plan to change your array values or wrap them into viewmodels which will do the additional logic, then you can write expressions also directly in the bindings.

So you can do the string concatenation inside the `css` binding:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: options">
    <div data-bind="text: name, css: 'option-' + name"></div>
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgmvvn2n/).

Comment: Awesome, How about other string operations? if my name variable have some underscore and if I want to remove them inside the data-bind. is there any way to call some js function inside the data-bind?

Comment: You can almost write any valid javascript expression inside the binding so replace will also work: http://jsfiddle.net/pgmvvn2n/1/.  However if you find yourself to put more and more logic into the bindings then it is time to reconsider your design and introduce some viewmodels where do you move these kind of logics.